# How do you make a picturebox that was made after pressing a button not visible when intersecting with a label?

Tags: vb.net

In my space invaders game, you press start, which creates 15 pictureboxes. When I hit the spacebar, a bullet moves to the top of the screen. What code would allow me to make a picturebox invisible that isn't named yet?

Answer (score 0):

your pic boxes should be stored in some kind of array or list or collection of some sort.

Like:

```
Private oPictures as List(Of PictureBox) = New List(Of PictureBox)

For index As int32 = 0 to 14
  oPictures.Add(New PictureBox .....)
Next
```

Then you can reference it something like:
`oPictures(3).Visibile = False`

Comment: Can you sort of tell me what the code is saying? I'm not sure how to incorporate that into my code.